# How to get the attribute of a tag from XML using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have the following XML and code that I try to save it in mySQL. It is working but my problem is that I can not get the product id attribute.

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null**

```
<product id="1111845">
  <name><![CDATA[MadBiker 600]]></name>
  <link>http://demo.com/p.MadBiker-600.1111845.html</link>
  <price_with_vat>107.01</price_with_vat>
...
...
...
</product>
```

Here is the code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("demo.xml");

   foreach($xml->products->product as $data) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products (shop, product_id, name, price, shipping, manufacturer, stock, availability)
            VALUES (:SHOP, :ID, :NAME, :PRICE, :SHIPPING, :MANUFACTURER, :STOCK, :AVAILABILITY)";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            "ID" => $data->product[id] ,
            "NAME" => $data->name,
            "PRICE" => $data->price_with_vat,
```

How to do this?

Comment: can you post your parsing code. Make sure to put '' in array fields ($data->product['id']) as php will attempt to find a const matching it and through a warning.

Comment: @Ray Yes I did now, thanks

Comment: Looks to me like `$data` _is_ the `<product>` node already (due to `foreach ($xml->products->product)`, so you are looking for `$data['id']`.  The fact that you don't see other warnings suggests you don't have error reporting turned on and displaying.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always when developing/testing code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Post is as an answer, I will accept it, thank you

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop iterates over `<product>` nodes already:

```
foreach ($xml->products->product as $data) {
  //...
}
```

So in this case, `$data` already represents `<product>` and you don't want to use `$data->product`.  Then it is just a matter of referencing the `['id']` attribute by array key on `$data` itself so:

```
"ID" => (string)$data['id']
```

(Don't forget to cast it to a string - and the other nodes will need the same treatment via `(string)`)

```
"NAME" => (string)$data->name,
"PRICE" => (string)$data->price_with_vat,
```

The fact that PHP didn't show other warnings suggests you don't have `display_errors` on. Always when developing code, use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Or set them in php.ini.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please tell me, if instead of the `<product id="1111845">` was `<product><id>1111845</id>` how can I have both as an option with a `||` maybe? I mean how does this work?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos If the `<id>` may be a child of `<product>` but otherwise certain to be an attribute, you could use `$id = isset($data->id) ? (string)$data->id : (string)$data['id'];`  If it may not be an attribute either, you would use `if (isset($data->id))...else if (isset($data['id'])...else...`  PHP doesn't have a simple way of switching between them with a conjunctive `||` like JS or Ruby do.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(int)$data->product['id']`, you need to cast attributes when using SimpleXML.

Answer (score -1):

**Instead of using**

```
$data->product['id'], 
$data->name,
$data->price_with_vat,
```

**use**

```
$data['product'][0]
$data['name']
$data['price_with_vat']
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: That would be looking for the first `product` node of a set of `product` nodes. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php