# How to show the value from a dropdown toggle bootstrap based on a criteria?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap dropdown. Using PHP I get the country of the visitor. So if the visitor comes from England or any other country not listed below, the English must be shown, on top and be removed from the list. as shown below.
I can do the PHP side, but what about the javascript since this is not a select dropdown and there is not a `selected` ?

Standard version:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">English <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="gr.html">Greek</a></li>
            <li><a href="it.html">Italian</a></li>
            <li><a href="cz.html">Czech</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

When a visitor from the UK comes in:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">English <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="gr.html">Greek</a></li>
            <li><a href="it.html">Italian</a></li>
            <li><a href="cz.html">Czech</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Here is what the HTML will be when a Greek enters:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Greek<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="en.html">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="it.html">Italian</a></li>
            <li><a href="cz.html">Czech</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: So do you only want to show English then or just English on top with the other ones?

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to show the "English" instead of the "Languages"

Comment: And the value you want to grab from the list under it?

Comment: @Rizier123 let's use the first two letters from every country

Comment: Make it simple, just show us how the html would look like if it should be English

Comment: @Rizier123 Done, I have updated in full to make myself more understanding, thank you

Comment: Ah now I see it. Now Do you want to print everything with PHP or is the html fix?

Comment: @Rizier123 Whichever feels right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php 

    $country  = "Italian";
    $countrys = array("en" => "English", "gr" => "Greek", "it" => "Italian", "cz" => "Czech");
    $default = $countrys["en"];

?>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo (($key = array_search($country, $countrys)) !== FALSE ? $countrys[$key] : $country = $default); ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php foreach(array_diff($countrys, array($country)) as $k => $v): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $k; ?>.html"><?php echo $v; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**EDIT:**

If you get the country shortcut and not the full name just use this:

```
<?php 

    $country  = "gr";
    $countrys = array("en" => "English", "gr" => "Greek", "it" => "Italian", "cz" => "Czech");
    $default = "en";

?>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo (in_array($country, array_flip($countrys)) !== FALSE ? $countrys[$country] : $countrys[$country = $default]); ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php foreach(array_diff_key($countrys, array_flip(array($country))) as $k => $v): ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $k; ?>.html"><?php echo $v; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. To clear my mind, if the visitors country is not included in the array, will show the en ?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Yes, just try it and you will see it :D (e.g. `$country  = "asdsfg";`)

Comment: I think I am missing something... My country is `$country = "CY"` . So I must get the english language since it is not listed on the array. And I get it. However, if I replace for example the `IT` with `CY` it was supposed to show `Italian` but not...

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos So the country which you get are the shortcuts not the full names? e.g. you get/have: `en, gr` and NOT `English, Greek` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying this earlier

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos updated my answer. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: Just out of curiosity: Why did you never accepted or wrote a comment on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25844992/3933332 ? For me it also seems that you used my code in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27698009/3933332 ; So was there a correct answer?)

Comment: I don't remember to be honest, but I accepted it now :)